# Problem accessing childNodes[] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript/HTML.

I'm learning my way around the DOM and JavaScript and am using the following page to explore accessing nodes via JavaScript:

http://franklyanything.com/test2.html

As you can see in the snippet of JavaScript I put in the Head, I'm trying to access the 2nd child of the `<html>` element, which should be the Body element.

However each time I run the page nothing happens and Firebug reports the variable as `undefined`. I have no problems if I change the index from [1] to [0]. This correctly identifies the `<html>` tag.

I'm stumped. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The true problem, I think, is that you are calling the code before the document is *ready*.

```
window.onload=function(){
  var theBodyNode = document.childNodes[0].childNodes[1];
  alert(theBodyNode.nodeName);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`document.childNodes[0]` is not the `<html>` element. It is the doctype declaration.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "...>
```

You can access the `<body>` node directly using `document.body`, and get its node name using `document.body.nodeName`.

If you want to access it using `childNodes`, try,

```
document.childNodes[1].childNodes[2].nodeName

// document.childNodes[1] => html
// document.childNodes[1].childNodes[0] => head
// document.childNodes[1].childNodes[1] => whitespace (text node)
// document.childNodes[1].childNodes[2] => body
```

If there is no whitespace between `<head>` and `<body>`, then, of course, the `<body>` element will be at position 2 or index 1 in `<html>` child nodes.

If you remove the doctype declaration, and the space between head and body, then your

```
document.childNodes[0].childNodes[1]
```

will work as expected.